# how to display nested ordered list with different list-style-type in ckeditor 4?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ckeditor

I maintain a legacy application that has CKEDITOR 4 integrated.
I am facing an issue with the display of the nested ordered list.
A user added an ordered list in this way using the bullet list plugin.

Please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

The source of this HTML code can be viewed using the source button. Here is how the source looks like:
[image]

But when the user is viewing the ordered list in the view mode, then it is not showing as expected.
Please refer to the screenshot here:

[image]

In the view page, there are many other css file which are used across my application which is affecting the output.

```
div.docSection ol li {
  /* list-style-type: decimal;  Commenting this line is solving the problem */ 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 2.0em;
  padding: 0em;
}
.sectionDiv li {
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  /* list-style: none; Commenting this line is solving the problem */
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

How can I make sure that the ordered list display is not affected in view mode. Is there a setting in CKEDITOR 4 for this? Can we solve this in css rules?

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found a solution to this issue. I had to use JQUERY to solve this.
Basically I am over-riding the css rules which were getting applied from Header Css files by Local css rules. The following is working for nested ordered list and nested un-ordered list but not mixed nested lists.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('div.docSection').find('ol').each( function() {
    var list_style_type = jQuery( this ).css("list-style-type");
    jQuery( this ).find('li').each( function () {
      jQuery( this ).css("list-style-type", list_style_type);
    });
  });

});
```